# At minutes in length

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I don't understand the function and meaning of the "at" in the following examples. Is the "at" necessary in these phrases? Could it be omitted?

> ***At over 17 minutes*** in length, it is a tour de force that requires multiple listens to truly appreciate its majesty. (Is it possible to just say  "over 17 minutes in length")
>
> ***At 5 minutes in length***, the complete "Murder to Excellence" is the longest track on the album. (Is it possible to just say  "5 minutes in length")

Comment: No, the *at* is not necessary. However, in your particular construction, it sounds slightly odd without it. (But not actually wrong.)

Comment: Could you explain the meaning added by the "at" ? I really don't get it why it should add to the phrases to be more idiomatic?

Comment: The *at* is understood to be there, even if it isn't. But it's *more idiomatic* to include it than to exclude because more people *do* include it than exclude it. There may be no logical reason for it—it's just the way it is. Note that you can also replace *at* with *being* or even *running*. The use of *being* or *running* would also sound a bit more natural than not having anything at all. (Again, simply because they are more commonly used.)

Comment: [multiple listens: buzzer]

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand the need for the preposition `at` if you put the sentence in more common order:

> It is a tour de force at over 17 minutes in length...

Or,

> It is a tour de force of over 17 minutes in length...

`At over 17 minutes` is a propositional phrase modifying the subject, `it`.

Comment: *It is a tour de force over 17 minutes in length* (without any preposition at all) sounds perfectly natural to me. You *can* use a preposition, but you don't *have* to—and frequently don't. So, this is a poor example. It is *less* idiomatic to exclude a preposition in the construction in the question—although it's not wrong. And you would never start a sentence with ***Of*** *over 17 minutes*, so your changed sentence structure that means to demonstrate different prepositions is a poor choice for that reason as well.

Comment: @JasonBassford, your version, without a comma, is using a different grammatical device, apposition, in which one noun is used to explain another. The original uses a prepositional phrase. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition, if you do not know the difference.

Comment: First of all, the use or lack of a comma has nothing to do with something being an apposition. An apposition without a comma is a *restrictive* apposition; an apposition with a comma is a non-restrictive apposition. Second, I only provided a sentence fragment in my above comment—I never got to the point where I would use a comma or not. (The comma in the text was not part of the italicized sentence.) But starting the sentence with *Of over 17 minutes* would be wrong regardless of whether or not I used one.